# Create log text file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, logging, text, text-files

I have been trying to do this with no luck so I've decided to ask SO.

I have a page with a bunch of different buttons and each button has it own parameters.

I want to create a .txt file as a log and then every time someone clicks on one of the buttons write in the log with the parameters and the button that was clicked.
Each button has its own function so I'm assuming I would just create the function and then add it at the beginning of each function using the function's parameters.

So I would need to create the txt file using onLoad() I guess, and then create a function to write in the .txt file every time a button is clicked.

I tried:

```
function WriteToFile(passForm) {

    set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");  
    set s = fso.CreateTextFile("logs\log1.txt", True);
    s.writeline("HI");
    s.writeline("Bye");
    s.writeline("-----------------------------");
    s.Close();
 }
```

but had no luck and I get an error saying Object expected at the beginning of the `set fso` line.

Any ideas on how to solve this or implement it in a better way?

**UPDATE**
So I just want to create a log file and get filled with data every time a user clicks on a buttons just so I know who is clicking what. All of my files are in a server so I just want to create the text file there and fill it out with information.

Comment: Are you sure we are talking about JavaScript (emphasis on _Script_) here …?

Comment: @CBroe well, I have experience with JavaScript and that's why I would like to do it this way. What else do u have in mind?

Comment: You want to log to a text file on the client's computer?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I have everything in my own server, so I want it to create the file where the rest of the files are. Something like `logs\logfile.txt`

Comment: Ajax Is the Best Option, and it will work fine

Comment: @randomizertech You can't do it like that, as JavaScript is running on the client's PC, not the server. Imagine if a user could use JavaScript to write text files to your server... yikes! You'll have to implement an AJAX solution or just use some server-side scripting language to handle your logging.

Comment: @MuhammadHaseebKhan any examples or tutorials?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev yeah, it sounds like AJAX is what I'm looking for. Any examples or tutorials?

Comment: @randomizertech well you could use a [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or [get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) but this will require something on the server to process and log.

Answer (score 3):

Say You have following HTML MARKUP with Different Buttons

```
 <input type='button' name='button1' class='capture' />
 <input type='button' name='button2' class='capture' />
 <input type='button' name='button3' class='capture' />
```

And when a button is clicked you get name of button and send it to server to write on logfile with following ajax call. Assuming you have PHP on server side

```
 $(".capture").click(function(){

    var buttnName=$(this).attr('name');
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      data:"ClickedButton="+buttonName, 
      url: "server.php",
      success: function(data){

      alert('Written in Log File');
    }
    }); // END Ajax 
    });
```

in `server.php` following code will be used to write on log file

```
  $myFile = "logfile.txt"; \\Considering the text file in same directory where server.php is
  $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
  $stringData =$_POST['ClickedButton'] ;
  fwrite($fh, $stringData);
  fclose($fh);
```

is not  simple?
**Note: You Need Jquery for this purpose**

Comment: I have no experience with PHP though :( I just paste that in a file and save it as php?

Comment: Then You just have to Change the Server side coding and then you good to go ;)

Comment: @MuhammadHaseebKhan I want to ask, can we log something over AWS Cloudwatch with this approach ?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript, in no browser (by default), has access anywhere in the filesystem. Not even a little own space. You might want to look into the HTML5 Storage http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage.

If a user would request for a `file.txt` with a log-report, you could generate a download call and fill the content returned with what is stored in the Storage object.

Comment: I don't want the user to know about this existing log, this is for developing purposes only to see which buttons are being used the most

Comment: Then you totally missed the subject of JavaScript's use. Everything on JavaScript's side (client-side) is visible for anyone. You will want to store that data on the server and retrieve it with XHR calls as your closest solution then. What server-side script are you working with?

Comment: @randomizertech if they are clicking a button, then you likely have some sort of postback... you'd do your logging on the server during that postback.

Comment: @Allendar maybe I did but I feel like this is going in the wrong direction. I just want to create a text file, hopefully using JS, and then write on the file every time a button is clicked (or a function called) it shouldn't be that complicated.

Comment: It can't be done, unless you tell your users to enable FileSystem-access first. That would never work sadly.

Comment: @Allendar what about creating the text file using `fso.CreateTextFile` ? Shouldn't that work?

Comment: It's a COM object, which will likely not work very well (or not at all) in most browsers. I don't see the issue when you are logging the data (even to a secure location) when executing JavaScript, the visitors can *still* see what you are logging. There are no secrets in client-side operations ;)

Comment: @Allendar well, the user only connects to an IP address, everything else is stored in my computer. So if I have a txt file to log all the clicks and the user wants to see it, that's fine. I just need to create the file :/

Comment: And that can't be done with JavaScript. It's not its purpose. Like Muhammad points out in his example; you need server-side script, JavaScript isn't that.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do this?

http://www.yaldex.com/wjscript/jsfilecreateTextFile.htm

If so, that uses an active x object. That would be an ie thing.

Comment: That's fine, I am using IE anyways

Comment: It gives me a warning about ActiveX, is there any way to not show that? Also, it gives me an error saying `Bad file name or number`

Comment: Are all your "users" also using Internet Explorer? Localized stuff is not advised. Especially the ancient ActiveX objects ;)

Comment: @Allendar yeah, the default browser used is IE8

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for but I am getting an error