# Jquery PHP Ajax data logger fails

Tags: php, jquery, events, logging

Working from previous question:
[Create log text file using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881108/create-log-text-file-using-javascript)
I'd like to log click events from a news scroller. The event detection works and triggers the alert.

```
    $("a.marq").click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      data:"ClickedButton="+url, 
      url: 'logger.php',
      success: function(data){
        //alert('req: '+url);
      }
      }); // END Ajax 
   });
```

Taking the php code from the referenced question, I created the logger:

```
   <?php
     // File: logger.php
    $myFile = "clicklog.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = $_POST['ClickedButton'];
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
  ?>
```

The click events trigger the alert and display the correct data, but nothing is logged by the server.  I checked server logs and nothing seemed to trapped.  The server is running Apache mod_security, nothing in the logs that I could spot.  It's simple "crawl-before-you-run" code, but I was tired of crawling and posted the question. I put the logger.php in the url root, touched the clicklog.txt file.

Comment: try for `data: {'ClickedButton': url}` and secondly check on your browsers console for errors, if its clean check for post data. And try to add `error: function(jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown) {//handle error here}`

Comment: @Franky  Franky, added   data: {'ClickedButton': url}, 
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('An error occurred... ');  No errors.  Didn't match your suggestion, but close, sorry, This is new to me.  Still no errors or logging. Any suggestions?  
    },

Comment: does it gives an error..?

Comment: No errors in console or alert.

Comment: try it in a different browser chome...

Comment: check for post data on console, and use `success: function(data){console.log(data);}` and hit the logger.php file manually from url. An use `$stringData = 'simple test-1';`

Comment: try to write the file using simple php code and if it executes without error and the file is written, then move on to jquery code, but first test your php code

Comment: Found something:  fopen(clicklog.txt) [<a href='function.fopen'> function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in .../logger.php on line 6, referer: http://atlbike.org/ Line 6: is the fopen.  Something to work on tomorrow. Late now.

Answer (score 0):

Apache write permissions, need g+apache, 774. 
Also needs 'a' not 'w' for appending to log file,   $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file"); Thx to commenters for error handling and other changes that may have helped.
Working code:

```
     $("a.marq").click(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data: {'ClickedButton': url}, 
       url: 'code/logger.php',
       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('An error occurred... ');
            },
       success: function(data){
         //alert('req: '+url);
     }
     }); // END Ajax 
   });



    <?php
   // File: logger.php
   // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     $myFile = "/xxxxx/code/click.log";
     $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
     $stringData = $_POST['ClickedButton'];
     fwrite($fh, $stringData);
     fclose($fh);
   ?>
```